# Patching .iso files

Tags: diff, patch

sometimes I have only little bandwidth. Also I have access to a machine with high bandwidth via ssh over the low bandwidth line.

So let's say, there's a new version of my favorite live system.
The old version are both on my local and my remote system. Actually I want to have the new file on my local harddrive, transferring only the differential data.  I tried downloading the new iso to the remote system and create a patch using bsdiff, but it uses to much memory (about 30gb for a 1gb iso).

One possibility would be to split the file to smaller parts and diff them.  What else can I try?

Comment: Copy your local old.iso to new.iso. Then use rsync to do the transfer from remote to local; it will use a dedicated delta-transfer algorithm. Calculate MD5 checksum on both machines to doublecheck.

Comment: yes you schould look in the direction of using rsync or maybe Google Courgette Tool will help you as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/q/12542591/751932

Comment: mpy: Add this as answer please.

Comment: Actually, rsyncing tails1.1 on tails1.1-rc1 transferred 400Mb. I don't think that was the best way yet.